# Custom fonts in rails 5 app and Heroku

Tags: heroku, sass, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline, custom-font

can you please instruct me on how to add custom fonts to my rails 5 application? i've added my custom fonts files to *fonts folder* in app/assets. i went on to use the @fontface and font-url in *.scss*, but my fonts wont take effect after before and[enter image description here pushing to heroku.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sAAA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go modify your application.html and add the fonts there. I don't know what you are trying to do but adding a simple

```
<link href="fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"; rel="stylesheet">
```

In your header might be enough.

Comment: the font i'm trying to add isnt hosted online like the google fonts. i've downloaded it locally, and i want to bundle it into the rails app i'm building